# Trouble sharing storage partition win10/ ubuntu15.05

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning, hard-drive, 15.04, windows-10

I'm having a strange issue with a duel boot I set up on my laptop. I have one hard drive (a rather small 120gb ssd) split into thirds. on the first third I have windows 10 installed. On the second I have Ubuntu 15.04. And the third is my storage partition. The problem here is after a few days I an unable to mount the storage partition in Ubuntu (still able to mount on win 10 just fine) and it throws the following error:

```
error mounting /dev/sda4 at /media/joe/B628F68528F64441: Command-line `mount -t "ntfs" -o "uhelper=udisks2,nodev,nosuid,uid=1000,gid=1000" "/dev/sda4" "/media/joe/B628F68528F64441"' exited with non-zero exit status 14: The disk contains an unclean file system (0, 0).
Metadata kept in Windows cache, refused to mount.
Failed to mount '/dev/sda4': Operation not permitted
The NTFS partition is in an unsafe state. Please resume and shutdown
Windows fully (no hibernation or fast restarting), or mount the volume
read-only with the 'ro' mount option.
```

I have tried unmounting the partition on windows, no dice.
I have tried formatting the partition on windows, no dice.
I have tried formatting the partition on ubuntu, dice. However after a few days the drive again is inaccessible.

Any ideas what is causing this?

Thanks in advance,

Joe

Answer (score 0):

You might start Ubuntu without properly shutdown the windows. If you are restarting and switch to windows to Ubuntu cause problem . similarly hibernate also like that so better if you try to switch to Ubuntu, then let the PC shutdown and give a little time then start with Ubuntu. Because file system of Windows is *NTFS* in Ubuntu its different so your operating system may confuse this student transformations.

Comment: Went to windows and shutdown properly and let the computer sit awhile. Still the issue persists.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you have not turned off *fast startup* option in windows.
**Fast Startup** (a.k.a *Hybrid Boot* or *Hybrid Shutdown*) is turned on by default in Windows. 
To turn it off : Go to `Control Panel` > `Power options` > `Choose what the power buttons do` 
 And the uncheck the `Turn on fast startup` option.
Hope that helps.

Comment: Hey! This worked! for now at least.  I'll see if it continues to work after a few days of use on both.

Comment: Also note that whenever you'll hibernate windows and then open ubuntu, this error will show up. For more help see [this](http://askubuntu.com/a/145904/398958)

Answer (score 0):

dual boot ubuntu 14.04 and WIN10 share NTFS problem same as described above:

1-Enter Win10 and open a cmd prompt as admin.

2-Change to shared disk partition (slice).

3-Run "chkdsk"

4- "shutdown" or "restart" and select Ubuntu from dual boot.

Should work now.
I had this problem when I did a Word 2013 save on the data slice.

I re-saved the file from WIN10 Word 2013. Problem disappeared.
Next time I used the "chkdsk" method. It reports no errors, but resets "something" that allows mount to work in Ubuntu.